# Boundary Pressure of a system in the Grand Canonical Ensamble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

Consider a system of fixed volume $V$ in equilibrium with a reservoir of both heat and particles (hence we may describe the system using the Grand Canonical Ensamble).

While I was trying to derive the "Density Fluctuations Relation" I have stumbled upon the fact that I need to use the canonical expression for the boundary pressure (so that I could differentiate it twice by $\mu$):
$$
P = - \left( \frac{\partial A}{\partial V} \right)_{N,T}
$$
however, I noticed that if I don't specify the value of $N$ then I get an expression for $\sigma^2[N]$ which depends on $N$ itself, which is impossible (the variance of a random variable can not depend on the random variable itself).

When I asked my teacher about this fact he told me that the expression above should be evaluated at $\langle N \rangle$ because we are assuming the system to be at equilibrium and we are describing it using the Canonical Ensamble, thus in the thermodynamic limit it contains $\langle N \rangle$ particles.

I would like to know if this reasoning is correct or if there is something missing. Also I would like to know if I am right in saying that books like Huang's are a little sloppy when dealing with these derivations (indeed, this specific derivation is carried out at pages 152-153 and Huang never mentions the problem, actually he just changes $N$ to its mean value $\bar N$ after "minor rewritings").

---

Any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: I do not understand why you need to use a canonical ensemble formula to evaluate the grand canonical density fluctuation relations.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Maybe "need" is not the correct word but both my teacher and Huang's text use that relation.

Comment: When discussing number fluctuation in the grand canonical ensemble, Huang works with Helmholtz's free energy to show a simple thermodynamic identity in a complicated way. Only thermodynamics is needed; there is no need to introduce a canonical ensemble.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I may be mistaken but at pages 153-154 there is exactly the expression I used above so I don't see how the canonical ensamble is not introduced there.

Comment: Huang does not mention the canonical ensemble in that derivation. Pressure, in the grand canonical ensemble, is provided directly from the log of the grand partition function. In any case, see my answer.

Comment: In any case, passage through Helmholtz's free energy is not wrong, although unnecessary. If one would like to follow this route, your argument is fine, and the substitution of the average number of particles with the fixed number of particles of the canonical ensemble is justified at the thermodynamic limit by the equivalence of the ensembles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that Kerson Huang's textbook sometimes has sloppy derivations. In this case, however, the book complicates a quite simple derivation.

Indeed, his formula for the variance of the number variable $N$ is (formula 7.38 in the book)
$$
\langle N^2 \rangle - \langle N \rangle^2 = z \frac{\partial }{\partial z} 
z \frac{\partial }{\partial z}  \log {\mathcal Q }(z,V,T)=
kTV \frac{\partial^2 P }{\partial \mu^2}. \tag{1}
$$
Where ${\mathcal Q }$ is the grand canonical partition function, $P$ the pressure, $T$ temperature, $k$ the Boltzmann's constant, $V$ the volume, $\mu$ the chemical potential, and $z$ the activity ($z=e^{\beta \mu}$).

By using the expression for the average number of molecules (formula 7.36):
$$
\langle N \rangle =z \frac{\partial }{\partial z}  \log {\mathcal Q }(z,V,T)
$$
formula ($1$) can be written as
$$
\langle N^2 \rangle - \langle N \rangle^2 = z \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\langle N \rangle= zV\frac{\partial }{\partial z} \rho = VkT
\frac{\partial }{\partial \mu} \rho\tag{2}
$$
where $\rho = \langle N \rangle /V$ and the pertial derivatives are at constant $T$.

The reduction of the partial derivative at the end of equation $(2)$ is immediate, without passing through the Helmholtz free energy, if one remembers that, as a consequence of the homogeneity of degree $1$ of the internal energy, we have the Gibbs-Duhem equation
$$
d\mu = -s dT + \frac{1}{\rho} dP.
$$

At constant $T$, it immediately gives us
$$
\left. \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \rho}\right|_T = \frac{1}{\rho}\left.\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right|_T 
$$
This is equivalent to the formula $7.42$ in the book, which can be easily recast in terms of the isothermal compressibility.

It is clear that, apart from a few formulas necessary for the context, the actual derivation is reduced to the last two.